# Are there any way to bring the images of the likes as well?

Tags: image, facebook, api, icons, facebook-like

Let me ask the question about the facebook API.

http://www.facebook.com/ceoofa/favorites 
We need to bring the Likes on the above page. But can bring only the texts without the images.
Are there any way to bring the images as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So simple dear. Just add `meta tag of og:image` like this in your head section.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL to an image">
```

Read Details from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/).